# 2 models 1 view query cshtml

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to display the results of two queries from two different tables in one view. I created a folder called ViewModels which contains a class with the following...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace BillingApp.ViewModels
{
public class importexport
{

    public IEnumerable<BillingApp.Models.IMPORT_TRACKER> IMPORT_DATE { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BillingApp.Models.EXPORT_TRACKER> EXPORT_DATE { get; set; }

}
}
```

IMPORT_TRACKER and EXPORT_TRACKER are the tables I want to pull data from. I want to pull data from the fields IMPORT_DATE in IMPORT_TRACKER, and EXPORT_DATE in EXPORT_TRACKER.

My view is as follows...

```
@model IEnumerable<BillingApp.ViewModels.importexport>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Table Selection";

string connString = "Data Source=SWDB10DSQL;Initial Catalog=BillingUI;Integrated     Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection db = new     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString); 

db.Open();
var imp = "select max(IMPORT_DATE) from IMPORT_TRACKER;";
var exp = "select max(EXPORT_DATE) from EXPORT_TRACKER;";
}

 @foreach(var item in Model){
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IMPORT_DATE(imp))

 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EXPORT_DATE(exp))
 }
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing. It's giving the error "Non-invocable member 'BillingApp.ViewModels.IMPORT_DATE' cannot be used like a method." and "Non-invocable member 'BillingApp.ViewModels.EXPORT_DATE' cannot be used like a method."

Comment: Just remove `(imp)` and `(exp)`

Comment: do this all in action not in view